# Java Changing date format for a specific day

Tags: java, android, date, datetime-format, simpledateformat

I want to write today's date in the following format using SimpleDateFormat:

Today, 13:14

On other days, I want to print it as date and time:

06.12.2021, 12:59

I can write in date and time format for previous days, but not in "Today [HOUR]" format during the day.

`textViewDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")`

Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

This requires two formatters and an `if` statement.

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Let’s first declare the two formatters.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter TODAY_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Today,' HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
private static final DateTimeFormatter ANOTHER_DAY_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

To try them out with different dates and times:

```
    LocalDateTime[] dateTimes = {
            LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.DECEMBER, 7, 23, 45),
            LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.DECEMBER, 8, 12, 34),
            LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.DECEMBER, 9, 04, 23)
    };

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    for (LocalDateTime ldt : dateTimes) {
        String formattedDateTime;
        if (ldt.toLocalDate().isEqual(today)) {
            formattedDateTime = ldt.format(TODAY_FORMATTER);
        }
        else {
            formattedDateTime = ldt.format(ANOTHER_DAY_FORMATTER);
        }
        System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
    }
```

When I ran today (December 8 in my time zone), I got:

> ```
> 07.12.2021, 23:45
> Today, 12:34
> 09.12.2021, 04:23
> ```

If you insist on being old-fashioned, I am sure the same trick will work with `SimpleDateFormat`. You will of course have a non-trivial task of determining whether the date is today or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a pre-existing date format that does what you want. So you have to do the conditional cases yourself.

If the date is in the "today" range (however you want to define that, regarding time zones etc.), generate the text using the "Today" format. If outside, use the generic format.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java +8, you can use Date/Time API (LocalDate) to calculate the difference between two date and check if its the same date or not, based of the comparison choose your format [Java Date Format](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/resolverstyle-strict-date-parsing/)

Comment: Using `LocalDate` and other classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is a good idea. Your link doesn’t seem perfectly relevant.